# Should we call a category method from self

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, categories, objective-c-category

It is basically a design question. I have a controller with large number of code lines in my application. I want to reduce the number of lines and for that I used a category.

Like If I have UIViewController subClass and I created a Category on that sub class. Now I want to call a category method from the UIViewController subClass.

I have question should I call [self categoryMethod] or not ?

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Which class category you are creating ? based on that your calling will work . please let us know little bit code or category class.

Comment: Hi @CodeChange I have edit my question. Sorry I cannot add a code here.

Comment: Why not? you are calling the method for the specific instance of the UIViewController you are using, it wont do anything to other instance

Comment: Category exist so that one can split your code into multiple files. Ideally you write category to group the related functions. You can call the function from using self and if that function doesn't exist it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can able to call category method with **self** object as its a object of same class `UIVIewController` so not any issue.

**Here are some more detail why we need Category:**

> You use categories to define additional methods of an existing
>   class—even one whose source code is unavailable to you—without
>   subclassing. You typically use a category to add methods to an
>   existing class, such as one defined in the `Cocoa frameworks`. The added
>   methods are inherited by subclasses and are indistinguishable at
>   runtime from the original methods of the class. You can also use
>   categories of your own classes to:

- Distribute the implementation of your own classes into separate
  source files—for example, you could group the methods of a large
  class into several categories and put each category in a different
  file.
- Declare private methods.

> You add methods to a class by declaring them in an interface file
>   under a category name and defining them in an implementation file
>   under the same name. The category name indicates that the methods are
>   an extension to a class declared elsewhere, not a new class.

So based on this description you can distribute your `UIViewController` code in small small pieces (files) as `category` and call it from your class.

One more way to reduce your Single class code is divide your `ViewController` in small part like You have `TableView` , `Header View` and `Footer View` , `Navigation View` so you can create sub class of this all View and write related code into that respective class and the main `ViewController` Class only contains data passing and general methods.

Use `ContainerView` is best practice to distribute your `UI` and code in small-small part.

Hope this will helps you to understand what you required!

Happy Coding.

Comment: Nice answer, Facing issues while accessing the private properties of viewController in category. If you provide any demo code or link that will be more helpful. Thanks.